# GPUImage build error on document target

Tags: ios, gpuimage

My last build was fine, but this morning I encountered below error message, any idea on how to deal with it? Thanks!

/Users/CompanyUSA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompanyProj-dvwzwewzmvvteifynwfiryybsdon/Build/Intermediates/GPUImage.build/Debug-iphoneos/Documentation.build/Script-BC552B3A1558C6FC001F3FFA.sh: line 5: /usr/local/bin/appledoc: No such file or directory

Comment: Anyone? I cannot figure out how to fix this.